# Element position in Canvas not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get an updated position of an element relative to a canvas.

In my code example, I add a label to position (100,100) in the canvas, then I print the position of the label relative to the canvas. I also have a button that will print the position when clicked.

When I run the code, it prints (0,0) rather than (100,100). But when I click the button, it prints (100,100).

What happens between the code in the MainWindow constructor, and the code activated when I click the button, that updates the position of the label? And how can I make that happen when I want it to?

I've tried using UpdateLayout() on both the label and the canvas directly after adding the label to the canvas, but neither worked.

code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Label label;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label = new Label();
        label.Content = "Boop";
        Canvas.SetLeft(label, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(label, 100);

        canvas.Children.Add(label);
        Point p = label.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas);

        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = label.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CanvasTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CanvasTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Margin="0">
        <Button Content="Button" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="50" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Update:

I have the same issue having the same code outside of the constructor, i.e. within the button click logic. If I try to add something to the canvas, then try to get the position immediately after, I get 0,0 instead of the position I set.

New code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Label label;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PrintLabelLocation()
    {
        Point p = label.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        label = new Label();
        label.Content = "Boop";

        Canvas.SetLeft(label, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(label, 100);
        canvas.Children.Add(label);

        PrintLabelLocation();
    }
}
```

Update 2:
Adding a async delay to allow time for the UI to render fixes the problem.

Code-behind:

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Label label;

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PrintLabelLocation()
    {
        Point p = label.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }

    private async void Wait(int ms)
    {
        await Task.Delay(ms);
        PrintLabelLocation();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        label = new Label();
        label.Content = "Boop";

        Canvas.SetLeft(label, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(label, 100);
        canvas.Children.Add(label);

        Wait(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling InvalidateVisual?

Comment: @PaulBaxter I tried it now that you've suggested it, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Even if you write code in constuctor to add the control inside canvas, it will render on page load. Till then the value would be zero

Comment: @VimalCK The same issue happens if I had the code to add the control within the button click logic. It seems to be some issue with adding the control and attempting to get the position within the same "block" of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content is not yet rendered, that is why at first it does not show your set location. Check out this changes I made in your behind code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Label label;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        label = new Label();
        label.Content = "Boop";
        Canvas.SetLeft(label, 100);
        Canvas.SetTop(label, 100);

        canvas.Children.Add(label);

        // Render event - when the controls are at the set location.
        ContentRendered += MainWindow_ContentRendered;
    }

    private void MainWindow_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintLabeLocation();
    }

    // This method allows reuse of code.
    private void PrintLabeLocation()
    {
        Point p = label.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintLabeLocation();
    }
}
```

This will allow you to understand a little more what happens. After the controls are rendered, they are displayed are the location set by you, and that happens after the constructor ends and the Window becomes visible.

Comment: This certainly does make my example code work, and does answer my question.. But I guess my example code doesn't represent my actual application perfectly after all. I have a function that adds an element to the canvas, then immediately does actions based on the position of the element relative to the canvas. The problem is, I always just seem to get 0,0 as the position. This happens inside a usercontrol, through some ui logic, and not in MainWindow's constructor, so I don't think I can take advantage of ContentRendered.

Comment: You can add an async wait of a set amount of time, after you add the control. That will allow the Ui to render the control. If this answered your problem mark it as answer, or update the question with new information.

Comment: Adding a delay does the trick! Even just adding a 1 ms delay seems to be enough. Thanks.